# how to add hyperlink in popup notifications in C# win form

Tags: c#

I want add a hyperlink in a popup notification (Tulpep.Notification) in C#.net win form.

**Code:**

```
PopupNotifier popup = new PopupNotifier();
//popup.Image = Properties.Resources.favicon;
popup.TitleText = "License inf";
popup.ContentText = "No of days";
//popup.ContentText = " https://www.google.com/";    
popup.Popup();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Click event when creating an object from PopupNotifier by simply calling `popup.Click += OnPopupClick`, then in the callback method you can open your site.

```
private void OnPopupClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com/")
}
```